# How to populate new date column to existing CSV file

Tags: javascript, node.js, csv, node-csv-parse

I am working with CSV file (~20MB). It has three columns as shown below and the file name presents the start time i.e. timestamp of the first row (in this case file name is `20200325131010000.csv`).

```
x;y;z
3;-132;976
3;-131;978
3;-130;975
4;-132;975
5;-131;976
3;-132;975
```

The difference between the timestamp of the consecutive row is 20 ms. How can I efficiently populate the new date column to the existing file? The final CSV file should look like this:

```
timestamp;x;y;z
20200325131010000;3;-132;976
20200325131010020;3;-131;978
20200325131010040;3;-130;975
20200325131010060;4;-132;975
20200325131010080;5;-131;976
20200325131010100;3;-132;975
```

So far I have tried the following code:

```
  const csv = require('csv-parser');
  const fs = require('fs');
  var json2csv = require('json2csv').parse;
  var dataArray = []; 
    fs.createReadStream('C:/Users/Downloads/20200325131010000.csv')
      .pipe(csv())
      .on('data', (row) => {
        row.timestamp= "20200325131010000"; 
        dataArray.push(row);
      })
      .on('end', () => {
        var result = json2csv({ data: dataArray, fields: Object.keys(dataArray[0]) });
        fs.writeFileSync("test.csv", result);
      });
```

The above code generates the following output (all timestamp are the same which is not desirable):

```
timestamp;x;y;z
20200325131010000;3;-132;976
20200325131010000;3;-131;978
20200325131010000;3;-130;975
20200325131010000;4;-132;975
20200325131010000;5;-131;976
20200325131010000;3;-132;975
```

The problem with this code is that it adds the same timestamp (i.e. `20200325131010000`) to all the rows. How can I correctly populate the timestamp column?

Kindly suggest me an efficient way to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this code should work and solve your problem.

```
  const csv = require('csv-parser');
  const fs = require('fs');
  var json2csv = require('json2csv').parse;

  const filePath = 'C:/Users/Downloads/20200325131010000.csv';
  const fileName = (/^.+\/([^/]+)\.csv$/gi).exec(filePath)[1]; // extract file name from path
  const intialTimestamp = parseInt(fileName); // convert string to number
  let i = 0;
  var dataArray = []; 
    fs.createReadStream(filePath)
      .pipe(csv())
      .on('data', (row) => {
        row.timestamp= (intialTimestamp + (i * 20)).toString(); // increase the number by 20 everytime
        dataArray.push(row);
        i++;
      })
      .on('end', () => {
        var result = json2csv({ data: dataArray, fields: Object.keys(dataArray[0]) });
        fs.writeFileSync("test.csv", result);
      });
```

Comment: Then I don't have new column timestamp. I need to have a new column and how can I populate it (adding 20 ms to get the timestamp of rest of the rows)?

Comment: Oh okay, I have the solution to your problem. I will update my answer and code snippet to have you get an idea.

Comment: @SaurabhChauhan I just updated my code, please test it and tell me if it works for you.

Comment: Could you please guide me: In the above code it writes json formatted data to csv file (it looks like `json2csv` doesn't seem to work). How can I store proper data in csv file?

Comment: @SaurabhChauhan I think you should take a look at the code example that shows how to convert JSON object to CSV formatted string: https://www.npmjs.com/package/json2csv#example-1 Hope it helps

Comment: No problems, don't worry about it.